# Determining $f(2)$

Tags: functions

> $$f(x+1)=3f(x)$$
>
> $$f(-1)= \dfrac{2}{9}$$
>
> $$f(2) = ? $$

Substituting $x = -2$ to get $f(-1)$ since it is known

$$f(-2+1)=3f(-2)$$

$$f(-1) = 3f(-2)$$

$$\dfrac{2}{9}=3f(-2) \implies f(-2) = \dfrac{2}{27}$$

I think I found $f(-2)$. However, how can I find $f(2)$ instead?

Comment: @lulu I'm still unable to get it.

Comment: Hint: $\frac29,\frac23,2,6$.

Comment: Why on Earth do you decrease $x$ when you need to go from $-1$ to $2$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust lol

Comment: Stop just regurgitating your homework onto this site at such a rapid rate please

Answer (score 1):

$$f(2) = 3f(1)= 9f(0)= 27f(-1) = ...$$

Answer (score 1):

From $x=-1$, you can extend the values both ways,

$$\cdots,\frac2{243},\frac2{81},\frac2{27},\frac29,\frac23,2,6,18,\cdots$$

Choose the right one.

Comment: Yves.Nice answer:)+

Comment: @PeterSzilas ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what you just did, but the other way around:

$f(0) = f(-1 + 1) = 3f(-1) = 3\left(\frac{2}{9}\right) = \frac{2}{3}$. Repeat.